# Heroku buildpack - Installing texlive binary package

Tags: heroku, latex, installation, tex, buildpack

I'm trying to install the `texlive-full` package on heroku through making a custom buildpack. I'm working on django application, so I'm currently using version of `heroku-buildpack-python` (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python).

According to this tutorial: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries
I found a binary package of texlive on http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/texlive-binaries (Links in the right column - *Download Source Package*) and I added these lines of code in python default heroku buildpack in the section `#Build time` in order to extract and install texlive-full on heroku.

```
# Build Time

# Switch to the repo's context.
cd $BUILD_DIR

TEXLIVE_BINARY="http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-base/texlive-base_2012.20120611-5.debian.tar.gz"
TEXLIVE_VENDOR="vendor/texlive"

# vendor awesome-vm
mkdir -p $1/$TEXLIVE_VENDOR
curl $TEXLIVE_BINARY -o - | tar -xz -C $1/$TEXLIVE_VENDOR -f -
```

After pushing the django application to heroku I can see that slug is 58.0 MB big (before it was just 10.0 MB), so it might have added texlive-full binary package to it (which is about 44 MB). However the latex equation on the site is still not showing and the same error appears; (That appears when texlive is not installed)

**ValueError at / latex returned code 32512 for formula:**

Is there some easier way to install texlive-full on heroku? Or what is the correct notation for installing texlive-full in buildpack or any other kind of debian package?

Comment: Why? There are bona fide reasons to want to do this, but if you just want to render equations on your site, use Mathjax, which doesn't need any software on the server. See stackoverflow.com/a/11793527/284795

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this buildpack](https://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex) I built my own version: https://github.com/syphar/heroku-buildpack-tex

It installs a small version of TeX-Live 2013 in your slug, and you can extend it by adding your own packages (collections or single packages from CTAN).

Since your (compressed) slug-size is limited to 300 MB on Heroku you can't texlive-full inside your application.

Answer (score 1):

This buildpack worked for me:
https://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex

Answer (score 0):

That error code tends to be returned because of problems with your path (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/latex-compilation-failure-on-mac-os-x-from-python-script) Follow the last step of the tutorial here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries and add the directory that your build pack works on to your path.